# How to translate the software specific expression "how to" in castellano?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

There's something in software or websites that is called a "how-to" section, it is like a frequently asked questions (faq) section but with a content closer to be a tutorial of how to do something in particular, or various things.

For example, on the right of stack overflow when you create a question and click on the tags section to add your tags there's a frame with title "how to tag".

I wish to translate that short expression (how to, not how to tag :-)) in castellano, keeping if possible its convenient shortness (the context is that I'm myself adding a "how to" section to my website **menu** and I need to translate it to castellano.)

Comment: how-to for what field? How to tag is: Instrucciones para etiquetas There is the noun how-to and there are phrases: how to [rest of phrase]. What is the topic of your website??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The obvious translation would be **"Cómo + <infinitive>"**, and a quick search at Amazon, for 'how to' books in Spanish shows this seems to be correct way:

- [Cómo Prepararse Para el GED](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764130285)
- [Cómo Descubrir Sus Vidas Pasadas](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1567180280)

The [Linux Documentation Project in Spanish](http://es.tldp.org/), refers to HOWTOs as [CÓMOs](http://es.tldp.org/htmls/comos.html). Although, even in English, TLDP's use of 'HOWTO' is a bit special.  They use 'How to' as a noun, as in "The Networking HOWTO" or the "DVD HOWTO".  But I suspect that may be what you're looking for.

Comment: yes but this is not really computer specific is it? I'm going to find multi-lingual websites that have a how-to section to see how they would translate it.

Comment: "How to" is not a computer-specific term/concept.

Comment: yes you're right, but how to define it then? You see in all other contexts there's not only "how-to". There's "how to + blah blah blah". You think I could use in my website the title "cómo"? It sounds so *direct translation* to me...

Answer (score 1):

Since there is not an acceptable literal translation, I would opt for a similar concept, like:

> Instrucciones (instructions)
>
> Guías (guides)
>
> Paso a Paso (step by step)

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo con http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=how-to

> manual
>
> instrucciones

De acuerdo con http://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/search?source=auto&query=how-to+manual

> guía práctica

Según mi personal punto de vista:

> tutoriales